# PHP MySQLi get the row using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, mysqli

I have this function that i created for getting the rows of data from mysqli database.

I try to used foreach but the only i got was something like i attached the image please view.

oops sorry i can't post image it required me 10 reputation to do that.

below :
Yes these is what i got `1 2 x M M n O O X`

my codes below with form and php

```
## FOR SHORTHAND DATABASE
if ( !function_exists( 'hs_debugSQL' ) ) {
    function hs_debugSQL($hs_db, $string, $debug=0) {
        if ($debug == 1)
            print $string;
        if ($debug == 2)
            error_log($string);
        $result = mysqli_query($hs_db, $string);
        if ($result == false) {
            error_log("SQL error: ".mysqli_error($hs_db)."\n\nOriginal query: $string\n");
            // Remove following line from production servers 
            die("SQL error: ".mysqli_error($hs_db)."\b<br>\n<br>Original query: $string \n<br>\n<br>");
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

## FOR SELECT SQL
if ( !function_exists( 'hs_getrows' ) ) {
    function hs_getrows($sql, $debug=0) {
        $result = hs_debugSQL($sql, $debug);
        if($lst = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            mysqli_free_result($result); 
            return $lst; 
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        return false;
    }
}
```

form

```
<label for="message_title">Send to Admin <span class="red">*</span></label>
<input id="name" name="user_to" class="text" />
<select name="user_to">
    <?php
    global $hs_db;
    $get_list_admin = hs_getrows( $hs_db, "SELECT * FROM hs_users WHERE user_control = 'admin' " );
    foreach ( $get_list_admin as $keys ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$keys['user_login'].'">'.$keys['user_login'].'</option>';    
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

connection from mysqli is fine as you can see i can get the data from mysqli.
but when i used foreach to retrieve the data it only show 1 number and sometimes 1 character.

i like to learn what is wrong with my codes for foreach.

thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array <- this page have to be FIRST one to check, if you have any issues with this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EXPLANATION**

The problem is here:

```
if($lst = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
     mysqli_free_result($result); 
     return $lst; 
}
```

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns row by row, you should loop through the result and returning the array. Something like this

```
$lst = array();
while ($lst = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $lst[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

return $lst;
```

EDITED:

Well, i see another extrange thing

```
hs_debugSQL($sql, $debug);
```

and in the form

```
hs_getrows( $hs_db,....)
```

Your are calling the function `hs_debugSQL` with the SQL you want to execute i guess but in your function the first param is the database link, and the second the SQL you want to execute. You should change this to match the params for the function.

And you are calling the function `hs_getrows` with the database link in the first param and in function declaration you expect the $sql so you should change this.

Comment: As it was noted in the other answer, the whole approach is just awful. So, having it posted again, ready to use - is apparently a disservice to the OP

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think that these 'helper' functions are making things more complicated than they should be. There's more than one problem here, but here's a crucial one:

This function:

```
    function hs_debugSQL($hs_db, $string, $debug=0) {
```

requires $hs_db, a dtabase connection resource, be passed in, while this code:

```
function hs_getrows($sql, $debug=0) {
    $result = hs_debugSQL($sql, $debug);        // where is $hs_db?
    if($lst = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        mysqli_free_result($result); 
        return $lst; 
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return false;
```

fails to provide a that key argument. Of course, further up the sequence of calls we find that `$hs_db` **has** been submitted, but has now been called `$sql` and the *query* seems to be missing.

Simplify! Get rid of these unhelpful functions, clarify what you are trying to do and make something work. Then if you feel the need to encapsulate some of this again, go ahead and do so knowing that the code basically works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a [real helper](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql)

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT user_login FROM hs_users WHERE user_control = 'admin'";
$admin_list = $hs_db->getCol($sql);
?>
<label for="message_title">Send to Admin <span class="red">*</span></label>
<input id="name" name="user_to" class="text" />
<select name="user_to">
<?php foreach ($admin_list as $admin): ?>
    <option value="<?=$admin?>"><?=$admin?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```